# How to show all records by clicking on ListView item in another activity?

Tags: android, mysql, listview, android-listview

I have created a listView that shows partial attributes of a record from the mySql database using JSON Parsing. I have shown 4 attributes in my listView and what I want is that when I click a listView item it display me all the attributes of that record in another activity that I have created; in which there are only textViews to display the information.

This my code:

```
public void updateJSONdata() {

mCommentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(READ_COMMENTS_URL);

try {

            mComments = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);

            for (int i = 0; i < mComments.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = mComments.getJSONObject(i);

String orderid = c.getString(TAG_ORDER_ID);
                String customerid = c.getString(TAG_CUSTOMER_ID);
                String type = c.getString(TAG_TYPE);
                String pricelist = c.getString(TAG_PRICELIST);
                String taxrate = c.getString(TAG_TAXRATE);
                String discount = c.getString(TAG_DISCOUNT);
                String orderdate = c.getString(TAG_ORDER_DATE);
                String requireddate = c.getString(TAG_REQUIRED_DATE);
                String shipper = c.getString(TAG_SHIPPER);
                String freight = c.getString(TAG_FREIGHT);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                String city = c.getString(TAG_CITY);
                String region = c.getString(TAG_REGION);
                String postalcode = c.getString(TAG_POSTALCODE);
                String country = c.getString(TAG_COUNTRY);
                String notes = c.getString(TAG_NOTES);

HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

map.put(TAG_ORDER_ID, orderid);
                map.put(TAG_CUSTOMER_ID, customerid);
                map.put(TAG_TYPE, type);
                map.put(TAG_PRICELIST, pricelist);
                map.put(TAG_TAXRATE, taxrate);
                map.put(TAG_DISCOUNT, discount);
                map.put(TAG_ORDER_DATE, orderdate);
                map.put(TAG_REQUIRED_DATE, requireddate);
                map.put(TAG_SHIPPER, shipper);
                map.put(TAG_FREIGHT, freight);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                map.put(TAG_ADDRESS, address);
                map.put(TAG_CITY, city);
                map.put(TAG_REGION, region);
                map.put(TAG_POSTALCODE, postalcode);
                map.put(TAG_COUNTRY, country);
                map.put(TAG_NOTES, notes);

                mCommentList.add(map);

}

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And here's my updateList method:

```
private void updateList() {

final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mCommentList,
                R.layout.single_comment, new String[] { TAG_ORDER_ID,
                        TAG_ORDER_DATE, TAG_FREIGHT, TAG_NAME }, new int[] {
                        R.id.orderid, R.id.orderdate, R.id.freight, R.id.name });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Intent extras = new Intent(ReadComments.this,
                        ViewOrderDetails.class);
                adapter.getItem(position);
                TextView OrderId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.orderid);
                TextView OrderDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.orderdate);
                String str = OrderId.getText().toString();
                String str1 = OrderDate.getText().toString();
                extras.putExtra("orderid", str);
                extras.putExtra("orderdate", str1);
                startActivity(extras);

            }
        });
    }
```

As you can see that I have showed only four attributes from a single record in my list adapter. And now I want to display all the attributes (there are 16) in another activity under onItemClick.
The above onItemClick is displaying the data on other activity but it is displaying the same values (i.e.the values of first listView item) for every list item. That’s where I am stuck !

Note: I have used only two textViews for testing but I have 16 attributes and I don't know how to display all the 16 attributes in another activity.

Please help !!

This is my other activity in which I want to show the complete information by clicking on a listView item:

```
public class ViewOrderDetails extends Activity {

TextView OrderId, CustomerId, Type, PriceList, TaxRate, Discount,
            OrderDate, RequiredDate, Shipper, Freight, Name, Address, City,
            Region, PostalCode, Country, Notes;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_order_details);

        CustomerId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvcustomerID);
        OrderId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvorderID);
        Type = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvType);
        PriceList = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPriceList);
        TaxRate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTaxRate);
        Discount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDiscount);
        OrderDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOrderDate);
        RequiredDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvReqDate);
        Shipper = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvShipper);
        Freight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvFreight);
        Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        Address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAddress);
        City = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCity);
        Region = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegion);
        PostalCode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPostalCode);
        Country = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCountry);
        Notes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNotes);

Intent extras = getIntent();
        if (extras.hasExtra("orderid") && (extras.hasExtra("orderdate"))) {
            OrderId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvorderID);
            OrderId.setText(extras.getStringExtra("orderid"));
            OrderDate.setText(extras.getStringExtra("orderdate"));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: If you can transfer two strings you can transfer sixteen strings.

Comment: Can you tell me how ? because I have only used four textViews in my list to display the 4 attributes and I want to display 16...!
And currently on clicking a listView item it displays the same information (i.e. the attributes of the first listView item) !

Comment: mCommentList has all records (all maps). So you have the actual map with map = mCommentList.get(position). And so you have all attributes al once. (Dont read attributes from the textviews. Not needed).

Comment: `adapter.getItem(position);`. Man you have it already here. But do nothing with it. `map =adapter.getItem(position);`.

Comment: I have changed the code to this, but still getting same value for all the list items !

mCommentList.get(position);

TextView OrderId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.orderid);
TextView OrderDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.orderdate);
TextView Freight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.freight);
String str = OrderId.getText().toString();
String str1 = OrderDate.getText().toString();
String str2 = Freight.getText().toString();
extras.putExtra("orderid", str);
extras.putExtra("orderdate", str1);
extras.putExtra("freight", str2);
startActivity(extras);

Comment: You only use three putExtra()s. That is not sixteen! And you still use the TextView's. Do away with the textviews as map contains all 16 items. Remember you put all sixteen in a map? Yes? Then now get all sixteen out en put them in extras.

Answer (score 0):

The way of retrieving value in OnItemClickListener is wrong. 
Try to do this changes.

1. Create List of Objects and pass to adapter and update ur view with
   List item Object.
2. OnItemClick get the Object from list than taking from
   adapter and fetching of value is also wrong. U should take from view
   but ur not taking from view of list. So, ur getting same values
   everytime.
3. Make ur Object seralizable so that u can send object directly in bundle rather than sending 16 values.

Create Object and add all ur 16 variables in the object and make the object serializable.
Then create list of Object and send to adapter.
Update getView method using list of object.
onItemCLick by taking the position, get object from the list u have created.
Send the object in intent to other activity.

I hope it helps u...

Comment: HashMap<String, String> map = mCommentList.get(position);
map = (HashMap<String, String>) adapter.getItem(position);

Comment: I've added these two lines under onItemClick, but it is still displaying same values for all the listitems !

Comment: You only need one of these lines ofcourse as they deliver the same map. These lines further do nothing. You will have to use map then.